# How do I get the text from this JSON file using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

Im using GSON to parse this JSON file:

```
{
    "database" : {
        "source" : "google",
        "items" : [
            {"title" : "hello world",
            "id" : "id_hello_world"},

            {"title" : "goodbye world",
            "id" : "id_goodbye_world"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Which ive read into `String jsonLine`

Im trying to parse it and output all the values but im getting a `ClassCastException` at the

`JsonObject source = database.getAsJsonObject("source")` line.

I think im searching for the data wrong. Im using this to search and output:

```
        JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);

        JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) jelement;

        JsonObject database = jobject.getAsJsonObject("database"); //Get Database
        JsonObject source = database.getAsJsonObject("source"); //Get Source
        System.out.println("Source: " + source.toString()); //Print source

        JsonArray items = database.getAsJsonArray("items"); //Get items array

        for(int i=0; i< items.size(); i++){ //for every item
            JsonObject item = (JsonObject) items.get(i); //Select item i
            JsonObject title = (JsonObject) item.getAsJsonObject("title");
            JsonObject id = (JsonObject) item.getAsJsonObject("id");
            System.out.println("Item " + i + " title : " + title.toString() + ", id : " + id.toString());
        }
```

If someone could correct my code that would be perfect. I know there are other simpler ways to do this using `GSON.fromJSON(jsonLine, Wrapper.class)` but im trying to learn to do it this way too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try `String source = database.getString("source");` so far?

Comment: Brilliant that fixed everything :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you are going to use `Gson` method, create your template structure:

```
class Item{
  private String item = "";
  private String id = ""; // for sure you can use 'int'
}

public class DataBase{
  private  List<Item> items = null;
  private String source = "";
}
```

Now your main class:

```
public class YourClass{
 private DataBase database = "";

 ....

 database  = gson.fromJson(yourString, YourClass.class);

...
}
```

Don't forget `try/catch` wrapper

Enjoy

Comment: Do i have to make a new class for every sub item? say for example it the array "items" contained another array called "dates" : [...] would i have to make a third class called dates?

Comment: The most importent thing in `Gson` to use the same field name like in json String. For your question under class `Item` put new `List<Ddate> dates` and so on

Answer (score 1):

use `JsonPrimitive` instead of `JsonObject`. (it must be internal bug of GSON, because, trying to convert `JsonPrimitive` to `JsonObject` was impossible, as far as the version of GSON 2.2.3)
So, your code comes like this:

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);

JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) jelement;

JsonObject database = jobject.getAsJsonObject("database"); // Get
                                                            // Database
JsonPrimitive source = database.getAsJsonPrimitive("source"); // Get
                                                                // Source
System.out.println("Source: " + source.toString()); // Print source

JsonArray items = database.getAsJsonArray("items"); // Get items array

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) { // for every item
    JsonObject item = (JsonObject) items.get(i); // Select item i
    JsonPrimitive title = item.getAsJsonPrimitive("title");
    JsonPrimitive id = item.getAsJsonPrimitive("id");
    System.out.println("Item " + i + " title : " + title.toString()
            + ", id : " + id.toString());
}
```

As Maxim Shoustin showed, creating template will be good solution for it.